# How to calculate the dynamic edit text values in android

Tags: android

I have created the dynamic `EditText` and entered the some value in it.Then If click new button the same `EditText box will be displayed below to already existing`EditText` also I entered the some value in that box also.I want to calculate the both value when i click total button.

Comment: Question is vague what are you tring to make an calculator.Please be specify the need with the your code that you have tried.

Comment: Can you make your question clear. Are you trying to add edittext dynamically to a viewgroup?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the pseudo operation

Make an Array of EditText first like this:

```
EditText arrayEditexts[];
```

After that on Create EditText Button do like this:

```
   arrayEditext[0]=new EditText();
   arrayEditext[1]=new EditText();.......arrayEditext[n]=new EditText();
```

Then on total button's click do like this:

```
arrayEditexts[0].gettext().....arrayEditext[n].gettext();//do what you want
```